# Switching between 4 screens in android

Tags: android

I have 4 screens. At first screen, there is button. When clicked, opens a map. Then after some stuff, it shows third screen. It shows nearby hospitals in map after searching in second screen (getting location, etc).  Then at forth screen, when clicked one of those hospitals, it gives info about hospital in textview.

Now do i need 3 activities and 3 xml layouts and so 3 classes? How can i pass parameters if i seperate those tree, for example the hospital list from second to third, or 3. to 4. hospital name? I can not figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a argument when you are spawning the new Activity instance using the putExtra method :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NewActivityClassName.class);
myIntent.putExtra("firstKeyName","FirstKeyValue");
myIntent.putExtra("secondKeyName","SecondKeyValue");
startActivity(myIntent);
```

And retrieve them on the new Instance using get[type]Extra() :

```
// getIntent() is a method from the started activity
Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // gets the previously created intent
String firstKeyName = myIntent.getStringExtra("firstKeyName"); // will return "FirstKeyValue"
String secondKeyName= myIntent.getStringExtra("secondKeyName"); // will return "SecondKeyValue"
```

Comment: is there any other way rather than using activity? For example in first screen button only. when clicked, button will be invisible. maps will be visible. then for 3. screen, reverse. that can weird? and before maps screen, button will call asynctask class and it wont return anything. it will update gui but but screen will be in 3. activity. how can asynctask can update that screen?

Comment: Or you use a Intent/Activity system to change between "screens" or you can make the different layouts and import then onto the main layout .xml and hide them all. Then when you call the second screen you change the visibility of the one relevant to what you want to display